# SQL Server: incorrect path to tempdb

Tags: sql-server

SQL 2022. To move tempdb I have changed the path to existing on other HDD but automatically have made an error: used `\\` instead of `\`. Now the SQL Server cannot start and writes logs:

`FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\\HimarsDB\\2022\\tempdb.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)`

How to fix it?

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Rebuild the `tempdb` database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15#RebuildTempdb) You may wish to, instead of resetting the database, correct the paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start SQL Server using the minimal configuration, by using the `/f` parameter.

Replace `MSSQLSERVER` with the instance name if different

```
NET START MSSQLSERVER /f
```

Then start SqlCmd

```
sqlcmd -S .\MSSQLSERVER
```

Execute the following script

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
'ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE (
  NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(mf.name) + ',
  FILENAME = ' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(mf.physical_name, '\\', '\'), '''') + '
);', '
')
FROM sys.master_files mf
JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.name = 'tempdb';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

GO
```

Close SqlCmd. Then execute

```
NET STOP MSSQLSERVER
NET START MSSQLSERVER
```

This is all outlined in [this blog post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/02/23/sql-server-how-to-start-sql-server-service-without-tempdb/).